# Detect & remove leading space in file or folder name

Tags: linux, bash, removing-whitespace

I need to detect and remove lot of leading spaces on my folders & files.

i try some code like :

```
find /home/account -depth -name " *" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv -v "$f" "...."' \;
```

but i couldn't find any code to remove leading space from filename or folder.

i need to :

```
mv "/home/account/folder/ folder 1"  "/home/account/folder/folder 1"
```

(because i use find, and make it detect leading spaces on sub folders)

how do i remove those leading space with code that i mentioned above ?
any advice would help.
btw, i'm using centos 7.

Comment: Can you clarify if you need to fix folder names, file names or both ? question text implies folder only, solution implies all files.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, actually i need to fix both files & folders, and the solution can do both.

Comment: Are you still looking for solution, or happy with accepted solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-name "* "` matches filenames having **trailing** spaces in their names. I fixed that below, and used `-execdir` to make it easier to remove leading space using parameter expansions.

```
find /home/account -depth -name ' *' -execdir sh -c '
for f; do
    mv -v "$f" "${f#./[[:space:]]}"
done' _ {} +
```

For a dry-run precede `mv` with `echo`.

---

If there might be multiple leading spaces then the convenient way is to use an extglob (which is a bash extension) in the parameter expansion:

```
find /home/account -depth -name ' *' -execdir bash -c '
shopt -s extglob
for f; do
    mv -v "$f" "${f#./+([[:space:]])}"
done' _ {} +
```

Comment: `find "/home/account" -depth -name " *" -execdir sh -c 'for f; do mv -v "$f" "${f#./[[:space:]]}"; done' _ {} +` it's working thanks Ismail :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find /home/account -depth -name "* " | sed "s/\/ /\//g"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use bash substitution to extract the file name, and eliminate leading spaces.

Minor note: the pattern `-name "* "` looks for file with a trailing space(s). If you are looking for a filter for leading space(s) use `-name " *"`, or for any space than `-name "* * "`. Sample code uses leading space pattern. You can adjust pattern and sed as needed.

```
find /home/account -depth -name " *" | while read fn ; do
   d=${fn%/*}
   b=$(echo "${fn##*/}" | sed -e 's/^ *//')
   mv "$fn" "$d/$b"
done
```

Comment: I don't know how many time I posted this comment but there is no point in reading find's output with a loop. A filename with ambiguous characters in it would break this. And also, this is useless use of sed as well; bash supports all posix parameter expressions plus extglobs, replacement etc.; thus it can handle such trivial modifications with internal functions

Comment: While I agree with the goal making every bullet-proof scripts, it's not always practical (and worth it) to make every script and one-liner support the most complex, and infrequent cases (new lines in the file name, etc).

Comment: Still, such answers might be misleading for future viewers. At least add a statement telling this answer won't work on some edge cases next time.

Comment: Personal opinion: You might be setting up the bar too high. Quick scan of recent answers (including top contributors) show many risky patterns being suggested, including issues like  'rm *' (which can be abused to 'rm -r' when files start with '-') , similar find/xargs and find/read issues, not to mention syntax error, etc. I think that it is a personal choice that each contributor will make, depending on context, etc. Having to include a long list of disclaimers, warnings on every answer is not the way to go. However, this is probably a good discussion for the 'meta stack overflow'

Answer (score -1):

use `rename`

- **-name "* "**       : matches filenames having trailing spaces in their names
- **rename 's/ //gi'** : replace space with nothing

-->

```
find /home/account -depth -name "* " | rename 's/ //gi'
```

Comment: I tried using rename, but the challenge is how to replace LEADING spaces in the file name only. I believe proposed solution will replace all space in directory and file name.

Comment: search only files not directories , use this command : 

find . -depth -type f -name "* *" | rename 's/ //gi'